# Таймер в js

Tags: таймер, javascript

Каков принцип работы таймеров на js? Будет - ли он выводить новые значения без обновления страницы? Думаю как бы сделать увеличение числа прямо на странице. Ну, допустим есть страница и число там увеличивается. Таймеры из интернета просто не подсказали мне ничего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таймеры работают без перезагрузки страницы. Вот вам простой примерчик http://jsfiddle.net/63PnG.

Answer (score 1):

- [setTimeout](http://javascript.ru/setTimeout)
- [setInterval](http://javascript.ru/setInterval)
- ["обзор" setTimeout и setInterval](http://alljs.ru/articles/timeout/overview)
- [JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)